# Method exists but it can't be called

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, vbulletin

I'm working with vBulletin, and I have to use the vB_datamanger_User class.
I've included the right files and the class exists.

I have to use a method called `set_userfields`, but it doesn't exists (in php opinion). 
The strange thing is that if I do

```
$newuser = new vB_DataManager_User($vbulletin,ERRTYPE_ARRAY);
$newuser->set('username',"MyUsername");
```

It works.

And if I do

```
var_dump(method_exists($newuser, 'set_userfields'));
```

It returns `bool(true)`.

But if I do `$newuser->set_userfields(array('field12' => 1));` it doesn't work (with no errors).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The method is declared as `function set_userfields(&$values, $verify = true, $all_fields = 'normal', $skip_unset_required_fields = false)`

Comment: Is it a private method?

Comment: It is declared as `function set_userfields(&$values, $verify = true, $all_fields = 'normal', $skip_unset_required_fields = false)`

Comment: "it doesn't work" do you get an error when you try to use it?

Comment: Or protected. Go into the php file and search for the method to make sure its a public method. If its `protected` or `private` there may be an accessor method.

Comment: @Edward No, I don't get an error. I also have done `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: If you don't get an error, why do you think _it doesn't exist (in php opinion)_? If PHP didn't think it exists, it would report an error from calling an undefined function.

Comment: If you don't get an error, then the method is being called. Calling a nonexistent or private/protected method will always cause a crash. You need to debug the method itself.

Comment: I guess that "does not work" means you get a blank screen. You also need to enable the `display_errors` directive. Make sure you do see errors (make an error on purpose if unsure).

Comment: It may be worth posting the method too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code looks like this:

```
<?php

class vB_DataManager_User{
    public function __construct($a, $b){
    }

    function set_userfields(&$values, $verify = true, $all_fields = 'normal', $skip_unset_required_fields = false){
    }
}

$newuser = new vB_DataManager_User($vbulletin,ERRTYPE_ARRAY);
$newuser->set_userfields(array('field12' => 1)); // it doesn't work (with no errors).
```

... you should be getting this:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference

If you don't, that means that you haven't enabled full error reporting in your development box. It has nothing to do with methods existence, which would anyway trigger an error as well:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method vB_DataManager_User::not_valid()

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out by enabling display_errors via ini_set().

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set the username as in your first example, you should probably be doing this:

```
$newuser->set_userfields(array('username' => 'MyUsername'));
```

Not this:

```
$newuser->set_userfields(array('field12' => 1));
```

As others have noted, calling a non-existent method will throw a fatal error. So the method is being called but just isn't doing what you appear to think it's doing. Probably setting the wrong field, based on what you've written.

[VBulletin Docs](https://members.vbulletin.com/api/vBulletin/vB_DataManager_User.html)